# Make UIImage full screen overlaying Nav & Tabbar too

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimage

I have a picture that becomes full screen with black bars to preserve ratio. The problem I'm running into is that it doesn't go over the navbar and tabbar as well. I'm guessing the part of the code I need to change is in here

```
    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

What can I set the newImageView frame to so it covers everything?

Comment: Unless you are going to present a new viewController, you need to hide the navigation bar and the tab bar.  See my updated answer for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the full screen image is behind the navigation bar and tab bar.

To set it to the full screen size, use `UIScreen.main.bounds`:

```
newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

When presenting the full screen image, hide the navigation bar and tab bar:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

When dismissing the full screen image, restore the navigation bar and tab bar:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

---

**Alternate solution**

As @LeoDabus mentioned in the comments, you can solve this by presenting a new viewController which contains the imageView that covers the entire view.  Present this viewController modally with:

```
self.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Note:  Setting `animated` to `false` will allow the full screen image to appear without animation.

Comment: same result as what i'm currently trying

Comment: @TommyK you need to present a new view controller